# Node js buffer.toString() encoding problems

Tags: node.js, encoding, buffer

Im parsing a website which is using Windows-1250 charset and for the last 3 days I can't get my page to show the data in the same encoding. My guess is that the problem is somewhere in getting the data from the buffer or to the buffer.
I tried installing the IConv module but there was a whole new set of problems so I was wondering whether there was a way to fix this without using iconv.

Basicly, Im getting "ANDRIJAŠEVCI" from the website and after the code below i get "ANDRIJA?EVCI"

```
    var options2 = {
        host: 'vred.hzinfra.hr',
        path: '/hzinfo/default.asp?Category=hzinfo&Service=vred3',
        headers: {"Accept-Charset": "Windows-1250,utf-8;ISO-8859-3,utf-8;ISO-8859-2,utf-8", "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2" }
    }

    var request2 = http.request(options2, function (res){
        var data = new Buffer(0,'utf-8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data = Buffer.concat([data,chunk]);
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log(data.toString('utf-8'));
        });
    });
    request2.end();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

1. It's `utf8`, not `utf-8` in Node.js, hence it can not work.
2. The website returns `Windows-1250`, but you deal with it as `utf-8`. This can not work, too.
3. Node.js does not support `Windows-1250` encoding, so this won't work using pure Node.js, no matter what you do (except you are going to convert the raw bytes, but I wouldn't recommend that for obvious reasons).

So, to cut a long story short: What you want is (hardly) possible without an additional library. Basically, you already found the way to go (`iconv`), but you wrote that there were some additional problems. As you did not say what these problems were, I can only give you the quite generic advise that your code should look somewhat like this:

```
converter = new iconv.Iconv('windows-1250', 'utf8');
data = converter.convert(data).toString();
```

Hope this helps…